# In episode 2 why is baka captioned with "Dick Suck"?

Tags: kekkai-sensen

In Episode 2, Zapp Renfro gets an introduction screen which captions 馬鹿 and バカ as "Dick Suck". At first, I thought this was a troll caption, but it appears in official releases such as the [Funimation! stream](http://www.funimation.com/shows/blood-blockade-battlefront/videos/official/after-the-phantom-ghost-wagon).

[image: Zapp Renfro]

Does anyone know why this was captioned this way? Possibly a reason/joke in the anime?

[image]

Comment: By official releases do you mean just localized releases like Funimation or does that also appear in the Japanese version

Comment: Because it's funny.... Do you expect there to be a deeper reason?

Comment: @Memor-X All the English text in the character introductions are present in the original Japanese release.

Comment: Chain Sumeragi is labeled "Shawty."

Comment: @senshin we are indeed always looking for deeper answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read [here](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/subcultures/blood-blockade-battlefront-kekkai-sensen):

> [image: Zapp, a "Dick Suck"]
>
> Dick Suck is a meme referring to an annotation shown during the introduction to the character of Zapp Renfro within episode 2 of the anime, with one of the introductory annotations referring to him as a “dick suck”. Due to the humorous nature of the comment, the term grew in popularity among fans, and is often paired with fanart of the character.

However, it's mostly a pun on *baka* as mentioned [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/3296bu/spoilers_kekkai_sensen_episode_2_discussion/cq931ve):

> > I think it actually says "Baka Baka".
>
> Yep, the kanji is 馬鹿 (baka) and the katakana says "baka" too.

As for the reason of its official translation being that as well, it seems to be for nothing more than humor purposes like senshin points out in the comments.

Something similar to this is:

> [image: Chain Sumeragi introduction screen]
>
> Chain Sumeragi being labelled as a "shawty"